# Using cell values as sheet values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some cells with month values and then I have some *sheets* with those values.

[image: Google Sheets, Cell containing months and Sheets with those month names]

In my *Script Editor*, **I have to use those cell values as sheet values**, so I'm doing this:

```
function PROD(cellMonth) {
  var val1 = cellMonth + '!G6';
  var val2 = cellMonth + '!G7';

  return val1 * val2 ;
}
```

But I'm getting `Result was not a number` as result.

How can I fix this?

I assume this happens because `cellMonth + '!G6'` it's a string value and not the proper way to call the sheet value.

For example, if I do this:

```
function PROD(input1,input2) {
  return input1 * input2;
}
```

And in a cell I type `=PROD(January!E6,January!E7)` I'll get the result I'm looking for. 
And if I do this:

```
function PROD(cellMonth) {
  var val1 = cellMonth + '!G6';
  var val2 = cellMonth + '!G7';

  return val1 ;
}
```

My cell will return `January!E6`, so I'm doing the product of 2 string values and not 2 numbers...

Comment: Review data types in JavaScript. Recognize that the Google Sheets application performs some value conversions behind the scenes, and if you want to use programming to achieve similar goals, you must perform the intermediate steps: convert a `String` variable to the value held by an application at the location that is described by the value of that `String`. This task uses the application's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the range and the value.

```
function PROD(cellMonth) {
  var rngString1 = cellMonth + '!G6';
  var rngString2 = cellMonth + '!G7';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var val1 = ss.getRange(rngString1).getValue();
  var val2 = ss.getRange(rngString2).getValue();
  return val1 * val2 ;
}
```